# Express.js callback in middleware

Tags: express

There are some codes like this:

```
function middle(req,res,next){
    //block A
    next();
    //block B
}

app.get('/',middle,function(req,res){
    DB.query('....',callback(){
        //block C
    })
})
```

I ran the code and the order of blocks execute is `A->B->C`, what i expected is `A->C->B`. I think there is a async call of DB. And the router return to `middle` didn't wait the DB query finished. How can I resolve this proplem?

There are details about my middleware:

```
function _AliceSPA3HttpParserPayload(){
    this.data = null;
    this.errCode = 'UNHANDLED';
    this.error = null;
    this.api = function(errCode,error,data){
        this.errCode = errCode;
        this.error = error;
        this.data = data;
    }
    this.apiSuccess = function(data){
        this.api('E0',null,data)
    }
    this.apiSuc = this.apiSuccess;
}

module.exports = function(req,res,next){
    var AP = new _AliceSPA3HttpParserPayload();
    res.AP = AP;
    next();
    if(AP.errCode === 'UNHANDLED'){
        return;
    }

    var error = res.app.get('error');
    var err = error[AP.errCode];
    if(!err){
        err = error['E-1'];
        err.code = AP.errCode;
        err.error = AP.error;
    }
    err.data = AP.data;

    res.json(err);
}
```

Comment: can you show the code in A,B blocks ?

Comment: Block A is some code for injecting functions to res object. Block B is about parser response data.

Comment: well `next` call does not block the execution of the function middle, it just tells express to go to the next middleware after finishing with the current one, can you move the block C in the callback of `DB.query` ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try move block C in to AP object and provide a flush method to trigger this function tomorrow. Express maybe shou provide a promiss driverd middleware pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be resolved in `koa.js` with a promise middleware.